# Hibernate Set to json

Tags: java, json, hibernate, serialization

```
public Class B {
    @Column
    private String name;
    private Set<A> values;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    public Set<A> getValues() {//manytomany
      return values;
    }
    public void setValues(Set<A> values) {
      this.values = values;
    }
}
```

I use alibaba fastjson to serialize Entity B and I got result

```
{
    "name":"blokwap"
}
```

the `Set<A>` is lost, in debug I see Hibernate transform Set into `PersistentSet`, and `PersistentSet` will not be serialized, I want to get the result like this:

```
{
    "name":"blokwap",
    "values":[
        {"x":"y1"},
        {"x":"y2"}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with fastjson per say, but may other serializers have the same issue. What you can try is to create a new object `ValueSets` which look something like :

```
public Class ValueSets {
     private Set<A> values;
     // getters and setters for values
}
```

And change the class B to have an object of ValueSets with getters and setters on the list object.

Comment: there are many simular code in my project, i don't want to create new classes everywhere, I tried to use List<A> instead of Set<A> and it works, will List<A> import performance questions?